# invalid sort function on second call?

Tags: sorting, lua, love2d

So I have a nested table

```
t = { a={},b={},c={},d={}}
```

..etc

Each item of `t` has a value in it named `F(integer) (a.F, b.F etc)`

Using `lua table.sort()` on t once with my sort function :

```
local function sort(a,b)
    return a.F < b.F
end
```

Calling the sort once is fine, but if it is called again it throws invalid order function for sorting.

I'm not sure why this is so and what I must do to fix.

**Info :**

The values and items sorted are not nil `(i assert() beforehand to make sure)`

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example?

Comment: solved, it was due to some reference to other items in table t and modifications to values in table t in the sort function. It did not like changing the tables contents inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

solved, it was due to some reference to other items in table t and modifications to values in table t in the sort function. It did not like changing the tables contents inside the function.